# C# WinRT : how to serialize a Dictionary object to JSON string and otherway around?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-store-apps

i am writing a winRT app (Windows store apps )

i have a dictionary object - in which value of a key could either be string , integer  another dictionary object or List of mentioned types. ( i dont have any custom class objects as value in dictionary )

i need to serialize this object to json string ... (the key would be same as dictionary's key and value for a given key would be according to given type )

i could do it myself by enumerating the dictionary but i wanted to know if there is any easy way already available for doing this ?

basically, i am looking for a generic method which does the work.
i have looked at DataContractJsonSerializer but looks like i need to add DataContract and other attributes to the object ( since my value types are limited and simple - i dont want to get into that hassle )

also, i want a way to convert a given json string back the the dictionary object ( again the types are same , no custom class objects )

Thanks,

Comment: As always, answer is Json.Net

Answer (score 1):

You can user [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/json) (search NuGet for this lib). This lib is free and work faster than .NET embedded. Just create several overloaded methods for different types of Dictionaries you work with. Like this:

```
// Serialization:
private string DictionaryToJson(IDictionary<string, int> dictionary)
{
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dictionary, Formatting.Indented);
}

// Disearilization:
private Dictionary<string, int> JsonToDictionary(string json)
{
    return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, int>>(json);
}
```

**Note**: you might also want to use async version of SerializeObject/DeserializeObject